# Make urls from blog posts title. Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in laravel and developing a blog website. What is the most convenient way to make blog titles links which will direct the user to the blog itself.

Comment: Slugs, so you can navigate to `website/blog/cool-blog-title` instead of `website/blogs/1`, but you'll have to figure out a way to implement that.

Answer (score 2):

For each of your blog posts, beside having a title, create another column `slug`, and when you are storing a blog post, slugify and store it too. Then you can use it in your queries and route variables.

steps:

in your migration add the `slug`

```php
$table->string('slug')->unique();
```

Put this inside your model, this will automatically slugify the title when you are storing the model.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function($model){
        $model->slug = Str::slug($model->title, '-');
    });
}
```

Then in your blog post accessing route:

```php
Route::get('/posts/{slug_title}', 'PostController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

And finally inside your controller/action:

```php
public function show($slug_title)
{
    $post = Post::query()
        ->where('slug', $slug_title)
        ->first();
    
    return $post; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has opened up my mind.